# Find Latest .bak file from multiple servers and copy the latest date

Tags: powershell-3.0

This is what i have so far

```
Get-ChildItem \\testserver01\m$\mssql\backup, \\testserver01\m$\MSSQL\Backup, \\testserver01\m$\MSSQL_TRAINING\Backup -Recurse -filter "*.BAK" | Select Name,Directory,CreationTime,LastWriteTime, @{Name="Mbytes";Expression={ "{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1Mb) }} | 
Sort-Object Directory,Name,CreationTime |
where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime | 
select-object -last 1 |
out-gridview
```

Each of those 3 server run backups for 6 diff databases .. So there are 6 files i need from each server 
right now it pulls the latest file out of all of them. I need the latest file from each server and from each bakup (there are a rolling 3 days for each database)

Comment: Can u make it more verbose, if you are able to get all files and get latest ,,,, where is the problem ?

Comment: i edited the main post

Answer (score 0):

Point to take care, Sort-Object will do sorting after collecting all data, so using sorting should be minimal and Out-GridView is not used as it is in Foreach loop.

And here it was collecting data from all servers and taking one from the whole list.

```
'\\testserver01\m$\mssql\backup','\\testserver01\m$\MSSQL\Backup','\\testserver01\m$\MSSQL_TRAINING\Backup' | Foreach-Object -Process {
    Get-ChildItem -path $_ -Recurse -filter "*.BAK" | Select Name,Directory,CreationTime,LastWriteTime, @{Name="Mbytes";Expression={ "{0:N0}" -f ($_.Length / 1Mb) }} |
    where-object { -not $_.PSIsContainer } | 
    sort-object -Property $_.CreationTime |
    Select-Object -Unique
}
```

Regards,

Kvprasoon

Comment: it needs to pull the latest unique file name from all the .bak files collected

Comment: if you need latest, then there is no point in unique, the code snippet is modified to get unique now.

Comment: tried that and got this
select-Unique : The term 'select-Unique' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:5 char:5
+     select-Unique
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (select-Unique:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException